# get contacts in a group google contacts api v3

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-contacts-api

How to get all members of a given group?

I am using the google contacts api PHP library.

I can get all contacts, I can get all groups but I can not get contacts who are the members of a given group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

I had to add group={groupId} to the query.

Comment: Can you tell the whole url after adding the group in the query.